# Create Equations using Lists

Tags: python

I have the following code which generates multiple lists as shown below:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    diff = []
    for j in range(10):
        diff.append(i*j)
    print diff

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36]
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54]
[0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63]
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72]
[0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]
```

I want to generate 1 equation for each column.

For example:

```
(element0_list1) * a + (element0_list2) * b + (element0_list3) * c + (element0_list4) * d + (element0_list5) * e + (element0_list6) * f + (element0_list7) * g + (element0_list8) * h + (element0_list9) * i = X
```

So, if I choose the second element from each row, an example equation would be:

```
0 * a + 1 * b + 2 * c + 3 * d + 4 * e + 5 * f + 6 * g + 7 * h + 8 * i = X
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Python and generate such equations?

I tried using multi dimensional arrays but I could not get it working.

Comment: what do you mean with 'generate equations'? is this a system of linear equations and you are interested in the solution?

Comment: Yes, a system of linear equations. I have included an example of how the equations need to look like. The unknown variables in the equation will be, a, b, c, d, e and so on

Comment: so `a, b, c, ...` are symbolic variables? (and: `a` can take on any value if it it always multiplied by `0`...); and the first line gives no constraint whatsoever. and your entries are highly dependent...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36],
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54],
[0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63],
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72],
[0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]])

coefficients = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h", "i"]
element_index = 1
equation = ' + '.join([str(i)+"*{}".format(j) for i,j in zip(arr[element_index, :], coefficients)])
```

Output:

```
'0*a + 1*b + 2*c + 3*d + 4*e + 5*f + 6*g + 7*h + 8*i'
```

Comment: I want to print out the equations as I have shown in the example in my post. Also, the equations need to be generated column wise instead of using each row wise.

Answer (score 0):

One way to print column wise instead of row wise is as follows, we create the list first, and then we use a double for-loop to iterate over it, we create the equation in the inner for loop, and print it in the outer for loop

```
#Generate the 2D list
diff = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    li = []
    for j in range(10):
        li.append(i*j)
    diff.append(li)

#List of variables
variables = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h", "i", "j"]

#Double for loop iteration
for i in range(len(diff)):
    s = []
    #Create the equation in the inner loop
    for j in range(len(diff[0])):
        s.append('{} * {}'.format(diff[j][i], variables[j]))

    #Create the equation string in the outer for loop and print it
    eq = ' + '.join(s) + ' = X'
    print(eq)
```

The output will be

```
0 * a + 0 * b + 0 * c + 0 * d + 0 * e + 0 * f + 0 * g + 0 * h + 0 * i + 0 * j = X
0 * a + 1 * b + 2 * c + 3 * d + 4 * e + 5 * f + 6 * g + 7 * h + 8 * i + 9 * j = X
0 * a + 2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 8 * e + 10 * f + 12 * g + 14 * h + 16 * i + 18 * j = X
0 * a + 3 * b + 6 * c + 9 * d + 12 * e + 15 * f + 18 * g + 21 * h + 24 * i + 27 * j = X
0 * a + 4 * b + 8 * c + 12 * d + 16 * e + 20 * f + 24 * g + 28 * h + 32 * i + 36 * j = X
0 * a + 5 * b + 10 * c + 15 * d + 20 * e + 25 * f + 30 * g + 35 * h + 40 * i + 45 * j = X
0 * a + 6 * b + 12 * c + 18 * d + 24 * e + 30 * f + 36 * g + 42 * h + 48 * i + 54 * j = X
0 * a + 7 * b + 14 * c + 21 * d + 28 * e + 35 * f + 42 * g + 49 * h + 56 * i + 63 * j = X
0 * a + 8 * b + 16 * c + 24 * d + 32 * e + 40 * f + 48 * g + 56 * h + 64 * i + 72 * j = X
0 * a + 9 * b + 18 * c + 27 * d + 36 * e + 45 * f + 54 * g + 63 * h + 72 * i + 81 * j = X
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print out the equations? Try this:

```
for i in range(10):
    row = []
    for j in range(10):
        row.append(i*j)
    print(f'{row[0]} * a + {row[1]} * b + {row[2]} * c + {row[3]} * d + {row[4]} * e + {row[5]} * f + {row[6]} * g + {row[7]} * h + {row[8]} * i = X')
```

## Output

```
0 * a + 0 * b + 0 * c + 0 * d + 0 * e + 0 * f + 0 * g + 0 * h + 0 * i = X
0 * a + 1 * b + 2 * c + 3 * d + 4 * e + 5 * f + 6 * g + 7 * h + 8 * i = X
0 * a + 2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 8 * e + 10 * f + 12 * g + 14 * h + 16 * i = X
0 * a + 3 * b + 6 * c + 9 * d + 12 * e + 15 * f + 18 * g + 21 * h + 24 * i = X
0 * a + 4 * b + 8 * c + 12 * d + 16 * e + 20 * f + 24 * g + 28 * h + 32 * i = X
0 * a + 5 * b + 10 * c + 15 * d + 20 * e + 25 * f + 30 * g + 35 * h + 40 * i = X
0 * a + 6 * b + 12 * c + 18 * d + 24 * e + 30 * f + 36 * g + 42 * h + 48 * i = X
0 * a + 7 * b + 14 * c + 21 * d + 28 * e + 35 * f + 42 * g + 49 * h + 56 * i = X
0 * a + 8 * b + 16 * c + 24 * d + 32 * e + 40 * f + 48 * g + 56 * h + 64 * i = X
0 * a + 9 * b + 18 * c + 27 * d + 36 * e + 45 * f + 54 * g + 63 * h + 72 * i = X
```

Comment: I need to generate equations column wise. I think, your example generates the equation using each row. In this specific example, the equations will look identify whether generated column wise or row wise. However, not in all cases especially if the elements of the lists differ.

Comment: Also, do you have a Python 2 equivalent example for this?

Comment: If i may ask, your rows and columns are the same, so it's not really easy to see if the print is being done row or column wise, could you update your example where rows and columns are different @NeonFlash